# External user domain in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

We're currently using Acegi 0.5.2 plugin for Grails 1.2.1. However, we're going to move our user management to external CRM. What would be the best way to link existing Person domain with external CRM entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom UserDetailsService class that will replace the standard one that comes with the plugin, and that can access your CRM system to get the user data. See http://grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Custom+UserDetailsService